# Calculating each Parabola's width and time know duration (bouncing ball)

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections

Using the known values below, how do I properly calculate each parabola's total Width and Number of frames (time) it should take to complete the parabola's full (bounce)? Currently each parabola has constant value of 20 frames, which are represented as points in the image below.

I have 4 known variables

- **Height = 20** : max height for the initial parabola
- **Bounces = 6** : total number of bounces
- **Duration = 200 frames** : total number of frames (time) to complete cycle
- **Decay = easeOutCubic** : determines  the decay of the bounces over time.

The image below shows what I have so far in my 3D application. Each parabola has a constant number of 20 points and the height decays over time using the easeOutCubic formula.

[image]

Comment: Successtive heights are proportional to the square of the [coefficient of restitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution) of the ground. Theoretically the heights never go to zero but only become infinitesimally small. Assuming that the $6$th "height" is less than $\frac 1{1000}$ of the first "height" this requires a coefficient of restitution of less than $0.501$.  Successive widths are proportional to the coefficient of restitution.

Comment: So in short would I be safe to just simply reduce each bounce's height and number of frames by roughly 50%?

Comment: It would appear to be so. You might want to check around for a good bouncing ball simulation app.